# Node.js Authenticate and Authorize

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, authorization

I am referring the book [Practical Node.js](https://github.com/azat-co/practicalnode) by [Azat Mardan](https://github.com/azat-co/). A blog project that has two types of users viz. (i) Admin and (ii) Normal User. The part that I am not understanding regarding Authentication and Authorization is as follows -

The main `app.js` has the code snippet

```
//Authentication middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session && req.session.admin)
    res.locals.admin = true;
    next();
});

//Authorization middleware
var authorize = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session && req.session.admin)
        return next();
    else
        return.send(401);
};

//Pages & routes
app.get(‘/login’, routes.user.login);   //This displays the login form
app.post(‘/login’, routes.user.authenticate);
app.get(‘/admin’, authorize, routes.article.admin);
app.get(‘/post’, authorize, routes.article.post);
app.post(‘/post’, authorize, routes.article.postArticle);
```

The user route i.e., `user.js` has the following code snippet

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next){
    res.render(‘login’);    //Pretty simple, it renders the login form page
};

exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next){
    //The sanitation check is not show here
    if(req.body.email && req.body.password)
    {
        //Here I assume, all credentials are correct
        req.session.user = user;
        req.session.admin = user.admin;
        res.redirect(‘/admin’);
    }
};
```

My question is, in the `app.js`, how the author has taken or made the following statements or am I understanding it wrong.

```
if(req.session && req.session.admin)
    res.locals.admin = true;
```

and further in the Authorize function also,

```
if(req.session && req.session.admin)
```

How can `req.session.admin` be true. We are setting `req.session.admin = user.admin` is the user route.

Please note: It is not just about authenticating Admin, but normal users should also be able to login and post articles.

Answer (score 1):

My name is Azat Mardan and I'm the author of Practical Node and the code you are referring to above.

`req.session.admin` is automatically available to you if you are using web sessions provided by the express-session middleware. `req.session` will persist between requests from the same client (thanks to session ID in their cookie). You can store anything on this `req.session` object including admin = true.

Answer (score 0):

When a user enters a username & password `exports.authenticate` is called. It isn't shown but this should lookup the user (say in a database) and then the credentials are set on the session, `req.session.admin = user.admin` (`user` is returned from the lookup).

All requests go through the Authentication middleware `app.use( function... )` and this checks whether the session admin flag has been set (i.e. a person has successfully logged in as admin) and adds that to the response.

All requests to admin areas also go through the Authorization middleware `var authorize = function...` and this again checks the session admin flag but returns a 401 error if a person has not logged in as admin.